# Call EFI_TCP6_PROTOCOL.Accept() as blocking

Tags: rust, uefi

I am trying to implement Rust std for UEFI as a part of my GSoC 2022 project. While trying to implement networking using the `EFI_TCP6_PROTOCOL`, I am unsure how to proceed. The Rust network operations are synchronous. However, the UEFI side is non-blocking.

So how can I convert a non-blocking UEFI operation to a blocking one? I think it should be possible by using the `ListenToken->CompletionToken->Event`. However, since this event should be of the `EVT_NOTIFY_SIGNAL`, it's not possible to call `EFI_BOOT_SERVICES.WaitForEvent()` on this event. So what am I missing here?

The specific function I am trying to implement is the `TcpListener::accept()` function. I know this can be non-blocking if the `set_nonblocking()` option is used, but the default seems to be the blocking. I will also need to make the transmit and receive stuff blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Create the event with a callback function, in the callback function set a flag to true.
Set the flag to false before calling Accpet, after you called Accept wait for that flag and call Poll in the loop.

The http example in the [UEFI specification](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Spec_2_9_2021_03_18.pdf) (Chapter 29.6.2.1) uses this technique.

You may not use a static flag for the sake of concurrency.